# Replace country names from an array with a code from another array

Tags: php

I have a dinamically builded array with some country names:

```
$countries=array('Czech Republic','France','Moldova','Romania','Serbia','Ukraine');
```

I want to replace these country names with their country codes from the second array:

```
$countryList = array(
'AT' => 'Austria',
'BE' => 'Belgium',
'BG' => 'Bulgaria',
'HR' => 'Croatia',
'CY' => 'Cyprus',
'CZ' => 'Czech Republic',
'DK' => 'Denmark',
'EE' => 'Estonia',
'FI' => 'Finland',
'FR' => 'France',
'DE' => 'Germany',
'GR' => 'Greece',   
'HU' => 'Hungary',
'IE' => 'Ireland',
'IT' => 'Italy',
'LV' => 'Latvia',
'LT' => 'Lithuania',
'LU' => 'Luxembourg',
'MT' => 'Malta',
'MD' => 'Moldova',
'NL' => 'Netherlands',
'PL' => 'Poland',
'PT' => 'Portugal',
'RO' => 'Romania',
'RS' => 'Serbia',
'SK' => 'Slovakia',
'SI' => 'Slovenia',
'ES' => 'Spain',
'SE' => 'Sweden',
'UA' => 'Ukraine',
'GB' => 'United Kingdom'
);
```

How to accomplish this?

**UPDATE**

Added Serbia to the array.

Comment: Who dared to downvote a question where three persons gave an answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PHP's `array_search` method can be used to find an array key based on a value. You can use this as the basis of a function passed to `array_map` to convert all the names into their respective code:

```
$countries = array_map(function ($element) use ($countryList) {
  return array_search($element, $countryList);
}, $countries);
```

See https://eval.in/907849

Note that Serbia isn't present in your list of codes, so that will be converted into boolean *false*.

Comment: I appreciate all answers, but I need to choose only one. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this:

```
for($i=0;$i<count($countries);$i++) {
    foreach($countryList as $key=>$val) {
        if($countries[$i]==$val) {
            $countries[$i]=$key;
        }
    }
}

print_r($countries);
```

P.S. Serbia code is not in second array, so full name stays.

Answer (score 1):

There is a function for switching key and value in an array:

```
$codeList=array_flip($countryList);
```

So for doing what you want, do the next:

```
$codeList=array_flip($countryList);
foreach ($countries as $key => $country) {
    $countries [$key] = $codeList [$country];
}
```

Comment: And then __what__?

Comment: Sorry, but with your code I get only this: `c, c, c, c, c, c`.

Comment: @Iurie: I corrected one tipo on the last line: `codeList[$country]` must be `$codeList[$country]` (the `$` was missing). Now it works.